# Can anyone tell me the name of this constant?

Tags: cosmology, physical-constants

I was watching a TV program about cosmology (I can't remember which or how old it was).  In it, it mentioned a fundamental number (which I'm assuming is a constant, but that's not necessarily true).  I would like to know what it is and what it means.

The number was shown on screen as:
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000138

Now, I'm guessing the number of zeroes as I did't count them, but there were a lot (the whole screen was full).

I know this isn't a typical question for this site, but I'm hopeful someone will recognise it.  Thanks.

Comment: I think I remember seeing the 'constant' in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf7BXwVeyWw 5 minutes and 28 seconds. Something to do with the amount of Dark Energy infusing space (per unit volume) to account for expansion.

Comment: I think it is one over the number of angels fitting onto the head of a pin.

Comment: @Hritik Narayan YES!  That's exactly it!  Wow!  I can't believe someone found it.  I was going to ask for the actualy video, but thought it would be impossible.  Thank you so much :)  If you would put this in an answer, I would upvote it.  I don't think I can remove the 'accepted answer', which is now wrong :/

Comment: You're welcome! It probably doesn't qualify as an answer but I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: Boltzman K_b https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant

Answer (score 5):

It is the Dark Energy constant (AKA Cosmological Constant).

It's 138 * 10^-121 in reduced Planck units.

Thanks to Hritik Narayan for actually finding the video I was referring to (number appears at 5:28).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf7BXwVeyWw

The video is of Brian Greene talking about why out universe seems fine-tuned for life.  He describes the constant as essentially the value that defines our particular set of circumstances (i.e. physical laws) in this universe - out of a possible 10*10^500 other values for this constant.

Answer (score 4):

The constant that has those last three digits as its most significant digits would be the Boltzmann constant $k_B = 1.38 \times 10^{-23} \, \mathrm{[J / K]}$, or 0.0000000000000000000000138, which relates the energy of the individual particles to temperature. No commonly-encountered fundamental constant has that impressive number of zeroes, unless you're using very strange units.

Comment: Planck's Constant is even smaller

Comment: I was referring to "the number of zeroes" in the value that OP mentioned, 1.38E-273; not that of kB.

Comment: Thanks, @Asa.  Yes, that's the one (I guess the font on screen was bigger than the one in my mind's eye).  Cheers.

Comment: @Asa, I was pointed at the actual answer I was looking for by a comment in the question.  What are the chances of those two numbers being so similar?  O_o

Comment: @Astravagrant I'm amazed that someone knew the actual video! Very intriguing talk.

Comment: Yeah! So was I.  So pleased to be able to re-watch it.  Very interesting indeed.